# Line seperators are not present in rendered markdown using react-markdown

Tags: reactjs, markdown, remarkjs, react-markdown

I am using `react-markdown` to render a markdown. The text content is rendered correctly but I cannot view the line separators under the heading and for the table. I tried pasting the same content in the demo `https://remarkjs.github.io/react-markdown/` and it renders correctly with the line separators .

Following is the codesandbox link for the implementation. https://codesandbox.io/s/strange-firefly-zzv3r?file=/src/App.js .
Note: The table does not have line separators between the rows and columns.
To render the table, I am using the `remark-gfm` as mentioned in the documentation for the `react-markdown`

Following is my React component that renders the markdown

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import ReactMarkdown from "react-markdown";
import remarkGfm from "remark-gfm";

export default function App() {
  const markdown = `# First Heading

  ## SomeHeading()
  Returns some heading if found to be true .
  
  **Syntax:** "SomeHeading(string; search-text; [case-insensitive])"
  |Parameter|Data type|Optional|Text|
  |--|--|--|--|
  |string|string|NO|The text to search in|
  |search-text|string|NO|The string to check|
  |case-insensitive|boolean|YES|set “true” if the search should be case insensitive.|
    `;

  return (
    <div className='post'>
      <ReactMarkdown children={markdown} remarkPlugins={[remarkGfm]} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: What "line separators" are you talking about?

Comment: @Chris The table is rendered without the borders and the headings do not have a line underneath. (which is present when the markdown is pasted in the demo tool for react-markdown).

Comment: Ah. You just need to apply some CSS. Markdown is about _semantics_, not presentation.

Comment: Thanks @Chris. I had applied some CSS to the page and it works like charm. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

In your example all the lines in your markdown start with 2 spaces. Spaces at the beginning of a line are not meaningless in markdown.

Comment: I have tried removing the extra 2 spaces from the beginning of the markdown and it still resolves to the same rendering.

Comment: Can you update your code, and either fix your 'codesandbox' or use jsbin so it's runnable for testing. Hard to tell what you're actually doing otherwse.